# Undefined behavior while using increment operator

Tags: c, pre-increment

I am new to C, i have an Increment operator program in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
  int a, b;
  a = 2;
  b = a + ++a + ++a;
  printf("%d", b);
  getchar();
}
```

The output is 10, can someone explain me how the output will be 10 .

Comment: Undefined behavior. Nasal demons.

Comment: Questions of this sort come up on SO pretty regular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined, the `++i` can happen in any order.

Function call arguments are also ambigiously evaluated, e.g. `foo(++i,++i)`.

Not all operator chains are undefined, `a||b||c` is guaranteed to be left-to-right, for example.

The guarantees are made in places known as [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) although this terminology is being deprecated and clarified in C++0x.

What's odd in your example is that neigher 2+3+4 nor 4+4+3 happened, so the compiler evaluated the left side first in one step and the right side first in the other. This was probably an optimisation to flatten the depencency graph.

Comment: It's not just that the `++i` can happen in any order: there's no sequence point around operators (except `&&`, `||`, `?:` and `,`), nor is there one around the `,` that separates function arguments. See e.g. [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §C and §5.1.2.3. If an object is both written and read with no intervening sequence point, the behavior is undefined (§6.5.16.3).

Answer (score 6):

```
a + ++a + ++a;
```

Behaviour for this is **undefined**.
The compiler might generated code that evaluated this as 2 + 4 + 4 or 3 + 3 + 4, but any combination/ordering of incrementing and accessing is a "valid" result.

Comment: couldn't it also be `4 + 4 + 4` (increments first?)

Comment: Not only that, but since the behavior is undefined, printing `42` or `Bad diff! No cookie!` is a valid behavior (just extremely unlikely in practice). So is making the computer burst into flames, or as the classical formulation goes, making demons fly through your nose.

Comment: sure, any ordering is fine. I just wrote examples that add up to 10.

Comment: @Giles the behaviour is *not* undefined, the *order* of the behaviour is undefined. Printing `42` is not allowed. (You were right, however, to correct my use of the term "associative".)

Comment: @Gilles: I'm waiting for like 10 years to a compiler that does those things. It looks like I have to write it myself.

Comment: why the Behaviour for this is undefined?